# Getting values from dynamic programming function

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am constructing a `recursive bottom-up dynamic programming function` which returns the number of coins for the inputted change. However, I want to modify the code such that the function also returns an array with the value of coins returned for Example:

```
Change:9c; #coins:3; 1c: 0, 2c:2, 5c:1
```

I tried printing the `values[j]` but only one coin is being extracted from the tuple of coins. For example:

at `iteration 7`, possible tuples are `(5,1,1),(5,2)` but I only got the last element of each, being 1,2 whereas I want the last tuple.

Below is the C code for this question:

```
    /**
  * @desc returns the number of coins needed for a particular amount of change
  *       using bottom-up recursive dynamic programming approach.
  * @param int amt  - amount of change to convert to coins.
  *        int values[]  - array of coins available (predefined).
  *        int n  - length of values[].
  *        int a  - current iteration of change (predefined at 1).
  *        int coins[]  - array holding the amount of coins from 1 till amt.
  * @return return coins[amt] - returns the amount of coins.
*/
int ComputeChange(int amt,int values[],int n,int a,int coins [])
{
    printf("\n\na: %d",a);
    printf("\n");
    coins[a]=INT_MAX;
    int j;
    //loops all values of coins
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {

        // if current coin value is smaller or equal than a (the current change value)
        // and if the number of coins at the current amount-the currently looped value of a coin
        // is less than the number of coins at the current amount.
        if ((values[j] <=a)&& (1+coins[a-values[j]]<coins[a]))
        {
            printf("%d,",values[j]);
            coins[a]=1+coins[a-values[j]];
        }
    }
    if (a==amt)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return coins[amt];
    }
    else
    {
        return ComputeChange(amt,values,n,a+1,coins);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int counter=0;
    int answer;
    int choice=0;
    int array[] = {1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200};
    int answers[100][2];
    int n= sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter change to turn into coins, -1 to exit:\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        if (choice==-1)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        int isFound=0;
        int coins[choice];  //array of number of coins needed up to amt
        coins[0]=0;
        for (i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            if (choice==answers[i][0])
            {
                printf("Cached Value: ");
                answer=answers[i][1];
                isFound=1;
            }

        }
        if (!isFound)
        {
            answer=ComputeChange(choice,array,n,1,coins);
        }
        answers[counter][0]=choice;
        answers[counter++][1]=answer;
        printf("Number of coins: %d\n\n",answer);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this function called? Give a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: `coins[a]=(int)INFINITY` looks fishy. Floating point values have a concept of infinity, integrals have not. If the intent is to use the largest value possible, use `INT_MAX` from limits.h and drop the cast.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `a`. Is it the current iteration or is it the current amount of change? It seems to be different things in different places of the code.

Comment: `a` is the current iteration, which is used to calculate the coins up to amount. `a` starts from 1 and increments each iteration till the value of `amt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that information readily available.

If you store the last coin for each iteration you can print the coins:

```
/**
  * @desc returns the number of coins needed for a particular amount of change
  *       using bottom-up recursive dynamic programming approach.
  * @param int amt  - amount of change to convert to coins.
  *        int values[]  - array of coins available (predefined).
  *        int n  - length of values[].
  *        int a  - current iteration of change (predefined at 1).
  *        int coins[]  - array holding the amount of coins from 1 till amt.
  * @return return coins[amt] - returns the amount of coins.
*/
int ComputeChange(int amt,int values[],int n,int a,int coins [], int lastcoin [])
{
    printf("\n\na: %d",a);
    printf("\n");
    coins[a]=INT_MAX;
    int j;
    int tmp;
    //loops all values of coins
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {

        // if current coin value is smaller or equal than a (the current change value)
        // and if the number of coins at the current amount-the currently looped value of a coin
        // is less than the number of coins at the current amount.
        if ((values[j] <=a)&& (1+coins[a-values[j]]<coins[a]))
        {
            lastcoin[a] = values[j];
            coins[a]=1+coins[a-values[j]];
        }
    }
    if (a==amt)
    {
        j = amt;
        while (j>0) {
            printf("%d, ", lastcoin[j]);  // Print the coins that make up the amount 
            j -= lastcoin[j];
        }
        printf("\n");
        return coins[amt];
    }
    else
    {
        return ComputeChange(amt,values,n,a+1,coins);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in order to cache the lastcoin, I can return lastcoin and move the block of `if (a==amt)` in the main function. Should I use pointers to access coins[amt] since the return is used by lastcoin now?